# Nsuserdefaults or state preservation/restoration

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have an image that is hidden and when a user shares using Facebook or twitter the `UIImageView` appears. When the user kills the app and relaunches the coupon disappears. I'd like to know how to save the images state whether it's hidden or visible. I'm sure it's something really simple, but I can't seem to solve it no matter what I search on the web. Would it be `NSUserDefaults` or something I put in the ApplicationWillTerminate area of the AppDelegate? If anyone has any ideas or code they could provide, it would be really appreciated! Thanks https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hXVH.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep `NSUserDefaults` is well suited to this purpose.

Be sure to set your flag:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"ImageShown"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize /* saves user defaults immediately */];
```

And to retrieve it back out:

```
BOOL shown = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"ImageShown"];
```

Comment: Thanks Gavin! I put the first piece of code in my  
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldRestoreApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder

&  the second in 
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldSaveApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder sections. Do I need to implement some sort of an @proprty method to use the variable "imageshown"?

Comment: You should just be able to use the user defaults wherever you need it; iOS stores them globally for your app, so you can call the `boolForKey` method whenever you need the value of the boolean.